# How come my flags don't add up?

Tags: support

Looking at my flagging history on my profile on the main Ask Ubuntu site, it shows that I've raised 170 moderator attention flags.

It further says that 165 were deemed helpful and 2 were declined.

That's only 167. What about the other 3?

Comment: *It's a new standard, 165 + 2 = 170!* Are there no flags still pending and waiting for review?

Comment: @Dan No, I've seen the 'pending' count in the past, although I've never noticed if they all added up or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offensive / spam post flags, offensive comment flags and suggested closure / reopen flags are not recorded as deemed helpful / declined if the flag aged away, i.e. if those flags were not deemed helpful / declined by a moderator within two days (for offensive / spam posts), within four days (for offensive comments) and if:

- The question's newest close / reopen vote is more than four days old AND

  - There have been no more close / reopen votes for the same reason since then OR
  - The question has received at least 100 views OR
  - The question has been removed from the review queue without it having been deemed to be closed / reopened
- The question's newest close / reopen vote is more than fourteen days old

(for suggested closures / reopens) from the date of the flag raise, as explained in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204327) meta post:

[image: image1]